# An array(0) is giving me a value outside of the range assigned to it

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, set, range

Im trying to assign some values to an array in VBA, the problem is that when I try print each of the values of the array I get one more value than expected because the first value is assigned to the Header.

I have the values like this:

1. A3  -  **Category** (Header)
2. A4  -  Global
3. A5    -    KAM
4. A6   -   Salesman
5. A7  -   External
6. A8  -   Admin

Here's my code:

```
Function xyz()
Dim Category as Variant
Set Category = Sheets("Reports").Range("A4:A8")
End Function
```

The values I get are:

```
MsgBox Category(0) =Category
MsgBox Category(1) =Global
MsgBox Category(2) =KAM
MsgBox Category(3) =Salesman
MsgBox Category(4) =External
MsgBox Category(5) =Admin
```

As I understand the Option Base of an Array is set by default as '0', so why is the Category(0) value considering the "A3" cell instead of the "A4" cell?

Comment: In your code `Category` is not array, but range object. Change `Set Category = Sheets("Reports").Range("A4:A8")` to `Category = Sheets("Reports").Range("A4:A8").Value`

Comment: ...and just to clarify: a variant array picked up from `myRange.Value` is always a 1-based 2D array (assuming `myRange` is not a single cell), regardless of the `Option Base x` setting you might use in your VBA module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sheets("Reports").Range("A4:A8")` is returning a `Range` object, and you can reference cells in relation to that range.  For instance, if you put a sample bit of text in the cell above your header, and you try `MsgBox Category(-1)`, it will show that value.

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Because `Item` is the default property on the `Range` class, you can reference it without explicitly using `Range.Item` (e.g. `Category(0)` in your example is the same as `Category.Item(0)`)

The `Item` property -- whether supplied explicitly as in `Category.Item(0)`, or, in your case, implicitly as in `Category(0)` returns another range representing the cell whose address is relative to your range.  That's why if you run my test and call `MsgBox Category(-1)` with a sample text in cell A2, it will show that text.

FYI: If you want to proof that `Category(0)` is actually itself a range, run `MsgBox TypeName(Category.Cells(0))`